# A particular usage of 'less seldom'

Tags: meaning

So, I've been reading *A Dance with Dragons* by George R. R. Martin. I've come across the phrase 'less seldom' and I would be really glad if someone explained it to me:

> Even so, there was something in the air that made Tyrion uneasy. West of the Rhoyne, he knew, the wharves of Volantis teemed with sailors, slaves, and traders, and the wineshops, inns, and brothels all catered to them. East of the river, strangers from across the seas were seen **less seldom**. *We are not wanted here*, the dwarf realized.

In my opinion, 'less seldom' should mean something like 'more often', but here it is used as 'more rarely'. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it's used as "more rarely"? It seems fine to me to understand it as "more often".

Comment: @d'alar'cop: I think it might be that Martin simply got carried away with his "convoluted, flowery" language here, and made a mistake. I just don't see how the literal ***more often*** meaning makes sense here.

Comment: same as "not as seldom"

Answer (score 1):

**Less Seldom** means more than before but still Seldom.  "More Often" implies that the frequency is closer to "Often"